# Add all paired numbers in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, nested-loops

I have an array like this:
    [20,40,60,60,20]
The requirement: sum any two number, if the result is divisible by 60 then count 1. Therefore this array should return 3 pairs. (20,40), (40,20), (60,60).

Here is the code I write but it gave me 4 instead of 3

```
function countPlayList (array) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++) {
      let a = array[i];
      let b = array[j];
      if (checkPlayTime(a, b) && notDuplicate(i, j)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function checkPlayTime (a, b) {
  return Number.isInteger((a + b)/60);
}

function notDuplicate (x, y) {
  return x !== y ? true : false;
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Why the `notDuplicate()` (`[30, 30]` should be 1, or not)? This might have to do with the conditions in your `for` loops. You might want to think about which elements you have to check in each loop.

Comment: The 3 pairs you specified aren't correct - it's really (20, 40), (40, 20) and (40, 20) - not the (60, 60) which will return false when notDuplicate is called.

Comment: Just as a note: this can be done in avg O(n). Modulo 60, the additive inverse is clear, so one just has to keep count: `arr.map(e => e % 60).reduce((p, c) => { p.n += p[(60 - c) % 60] || 0; p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1; return p; }, { n: 0 }).n`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems in your code

1. you are not running on the whole array, you either need to run `(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` or `(let i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++)`
2. the inner loop need to start from from the outer index + 1 so you won't check every combination twice.

```js
function countPlayList (array) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      let a = array[i];
      let b = array[j];
      if (checkPlayTime(a, b)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function checkPlayTime (a, b) {
  return Number.isInteger((a + b)/60);
}

console.log(countPlayList([20,40,60,60,20]));
```

btw there is no need for `return x !== y ? true : false;` 
you can just `return x !== y;` as this value is already boolean;

Comment: the outer has to check until the item before the last item.

Answer (score 1):

Start the second loop from `i+1` since you have taken the ith index already in the first loop then you have to traverse from `i+1` to length of the array, also run the both loop till `i < array.length` since you are starting from `index` 0

```js
function countPlayList (array) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
      let a = array[i];
      let b = array[j];
      if (checkPlayTime(a, b) && notDuplicate(i, j)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function checkPlayTime (a, b) {
  return Number.isInteger((a + b)/60);
}

function notDuplicate (x, y) {
  return x !== y ? true : false;
}
console.log(countPlayList([20,40,60,60,20]))
```

Comment: _"run the **both** loop till `i < array.length`"_ - That's (partly) unnecessary.

Comment: @Andreas I think that is necessary, the first loop  covers from` i = 0 to arraylength - 1`, second loop from `j = i+1 to arraylength - 1`, else intermediate nodes will be missing right?

Comment: Why would you want to check `array[array.length - 1] + array[array.length - 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You could change some parts:

- iterate the inner from `i + 1` until smaller than `length` of the array,
- use a stringed value of the actual pair,
- use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for keeping track of seen pairs,
- use a different check for summing and use the remainder operator for getting the rest,
- use a check for seen values,
- store an unseen pair,
- return `size` of `pairs` as count.

```js
function countPlayList(array) {
    let pairs = new Set;
        
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            let a = array[i],
                b = array[j],
                pair = [a, b].join('|');
                
            if ((a + b) % 60 === 0 && !pairs.has(pair)) {
                pairs.add(pair);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(...pairs);
    return pairs.size;
}

console.log(countPlayList([20, 40, 60, 60, 20]));
```